# Crop Intent doesn't work properly in Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent

Here is my intent code for select picture and cropping from gallery.

```
 int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 100;
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 150);
                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 150);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete using with."), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Here is my onActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 100;
    Bundle extras = null;
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        extras = data.getExtras();
    }
    if (extras != null) {
        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
        ImageView profilePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
        profilePhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
```

These codes above crop&set image successfully. However, sometimes it doesn't work properly. I mean when I'm using 3rd party gallery app instead of using device's default gallery app. It doesn't set the image. This may be not getting file path correctly when using another gallery app. So , how can I implement select&crop and set image into imageview ? I researched on to internet but nothing solved this problem so far.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my intent code for select picture and cropping from gallery.

No, that is code for selecting a picture. The various extras that you have on there are not part of [the `ACTION_PICK` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK), or any other official documentation, for that matter.

> These codes above crop&set image successfully

Not generally.

> However, sometimes it doesn't work properly. I mean when I'm using 3rd party gallery app instead of using device's default gallery app.

There are thousands of Android device models. There is no single "default gallery app" for all of them; there will be dozens, if not hundreds, of "default gallery app" implementations. None have to support the random extras that you are trying. Also, none have to return something in a `data` extra, as `ACTION_PICK` returns a `Uri` in the result `Intent`, as is covered in [the documentation for `ACTION_PICK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK).

> So , how can I implement select&crop and set image into imageview ?

Get rid of the extras. Get rid of the `extras.getParcelable("data")` bit. Get the `Uri` of the picked image (`data.getData()`). Use that in conjunction with one of various [image cropping libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available for Android.

Comment: I also used ACTION_GET_CONTENT but result is the same. Besides can you give me code example ? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Musti: "I also used ACTION_GET_CONTENT but result is the same" -- as I wrote, "the various extras that you have on there are not part of the ACTION_PICK documentation, **or any other official documentation**" (emphasis added). Those extras are not documented for any action string. "Besides can you give me code example ?" -- choose a library that has a code example.